# how to get default Font setting in Mozilla WebExtension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am writing a Firefox Add-on and I need to get default font set at `Option => Content => Fonts & Colors` also shown in the picture below, in this case, `Tohama`. Is it possilble to get it programmatically. If possible, can anyone give me solution with sample code.

[image]